# Boolean Operation without New Vertices

Tags: modifiers

This may sound strange, but I have need for a boolean operation that only cuts the edges of the target, and these are the only new vertices that are created.

Best explained with a picture:

First: Two objects || Second: Usual Behavior || Third: Desired Behavior

[image]

Comment: The base mesh shouldn't be that dense in this case. Result of Boolean will have the same topology as its input, so better redo base mesh (maybe Decimate mod) or use another mesh.

Comment: You can also have a look to 'knife project' in the tools panel of the edit mode (select the cutting mesh, shift select the mesh to cut, enter edit mode, place the 3D view in the wanted angle, and use 'knife project')